# React-Native 0.56 how to enable Android gif support with fresco?

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

After updating from RN 0.55 to 0.56, GIF are not working anymore on Android?

My `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I figured out that React Native 0.56 use **Fresco 1.9.0**, and also that fresco 1.9.0 **does not need animated-base-support**, so the following `app/build.gradle` will work

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.9.0'
}
```

`fresco-animated-gif` needs to be sync with [ReactAndroid/build.gradle](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/build.gradle#L300).